# How to create mouse adapter in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mouseevent, tornadofx

I am trying to create a `mouse adapter` to handle when a mouse button to print something. I have created a class and extended the mouse adapter. I override the mouseClicked method and now I to intialize the new object but i dont know what the argument is

What I tried

Created the MouseAdapterEvent where i override the mouseClicked method

```
class MouseAdapterEvents: MouseAdapter() {
    override fun mouseClicked(e: java.awt.event.MouseEvent?) {
        print("something")
    }
}
```

then created the object in my other class

```
var a:MouseAdapterEvents
```

then in an async I'm waiting for mouse to be clicked `a.mouseClicked()` but i dont know what the argument is.

What should i put there?
And tbh i don't know how to initialize this var either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [initialize class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#creating-instances-of-classes) by

```kotlin
var a:MouseAdapterEvents = MouseAdapterEvents()
```

and if you don't want to create new class you can use [Object Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions)

```kotlin
var a = object: MouseAdapter() {
    override fun mouseClicked(e: java.awt.event.MouseEvent) {
        print("something")
    }
}
```